# Concatenate a variable in a string so as to form a URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to consume an API which has to be specific for given users based on a variable: their cooker ID.

As such, below is the script I wrote in order to achieve that: I'm parsing the variable as `${cookieuid}` in a string so as to form the URL;

```
getBellNotification() {
    let cookieuid = this.currentUser;
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.authorizeHeaders(headers);
    return this.http.get(
        this.config.apiUrl + 'api/supplier-notification/${cookieuid}?_format=json', {
            headers: headers
        }
    )
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}
```

It is not working as expected as I get the result below, with undesired special characters:

```
http://<url>/api/supplier-notification/$%7Bcookieuid%7D?_format=json
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve that?

I've tried other ways but still cannot get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
getBellNotification(){
        let cookieuid = this.currentUser;
        const url = `${this.config.apiUrl}/api/supplier-notification/${cookieuid}?_format=json`;
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.authorizeHeaders(headers);
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers })
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan. I tried other way like this  let urlPre = 'api/supplier-notification/';    let urlPost = '?_format=json'; then concatenated with +